# jQuery is not properly hiding/showing elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following html and jQuery code in my web template.

The $.getJSON call can take some time, so I wanted to show a warning (div with id="warning") while the data is loading so the user knows to wait for it.

The code correctly validates the status dropdown, and will return the correct data for the table, and the table displays fine.

However, when the submit button is clicked, the warning paragraph does not show up, and the table is still visible whilst the data is loading.

How can I make the table disappear while the data is loading and show the warning also?

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <form id="search_form">
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-4">
                  {{ render_field(form.status) }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4">
                  <input type="submit" value="Get Issues" id="submit">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div hidden="true" id="warning" class="col-xs-12 center alert alert-warning">
              <p>Data is loading, this might take a few seconds</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div id="errors" hidden="true" class="col-xs-12 center alert alert-danger">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </form>
```

```
  <script>
  var table;
  $('#submit').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      if (!$('#status').val()) {
          $('#errors').html('');
          $("<p>Please select a status</p>").appendTo($('#errors'));
          $("#errors").show();
          $("#table_div").hide();
          return;
      } else {
          $("#errors").hide();
      }

      $("#warning").show();
      //get the data for the table
      $.getJSON("/all_issues/status/" + $("#status").val(), function(data) {
          table = $('#search_table').dataTable( {
              destroy: true,
              "data": data,
          });
          $('#table_div').show();
      });
      $("#warning").hide();
  });
```

Comment: Move `$("#warning").hide();` inside your `$.getJSON()` callback

Comment: Try placing your `$.getJSON` (along with `hide` - or move that into the callback of `getJSON`) into a `setTimeout` to see if that helps.

Comment: @dave, make that an answer, and I will accept it! That worked for me.

Comment: @Mark glad I could help. I added this as [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31014037/361762)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `$("#warning").hide()` inside your `$.getJSON()` callback.

[`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is an AJAX call, so the callback is executed asynchronously. In your current setup you are hiding your `<div id="warning">` right after you show it, when instead you want to hide it after your JSON is loaded.